# Script that takes in a keyword and a category from user and finds all instances of keyword in files of that category

Tags: shell, scripting

I'm new to scripts. In the context of work, I was tasked with creating a script that takes in two values from the user (keyword and category).**[Step A]**

Then, the script should search a repo of files for the folder that has the same name as the category. (In the context of this script, a category will correspond to a folder name) **[Step B]**

Once found, it should copy the files in that folder to a new temporary folder that it creates. **[Step C]**

After that, the script should search for every instance of the keyword in the files of the temp folder and return them. **[Step D]**

The last step is to delete the temporary folder. **[Step E]**

I know the scripts are in Korn Shell(if that makes any sense). Do you guys have any tips on what documentation to read so that I can find what I'm looking for for any of the steps? At the moment I have this for Step A:

```
echo "Please enter category"
read category
echo $category

echo "Please enter keyword"
read keyword
echo $keyword
```

Is this the correct way to go?

Comment: Why copy the files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have come up with simple bash script that does the above tasks.
Feel free to change the directory names and folder names as required. you can also mention them in separate configs and refer them in the main script.

```
#!/bin/bash
#Read the input from user 

read -p "Enter a keyWord: " keyword
read -p "Enter a category : " category`

#search for the folder in the mentioned directory. 

folder=$(find /path/to/repo -type d -name "$category")

#create a temp directory 
temp_dir="/path/to/temp_folder" 
mkdir -p "$temp_dir"

#copy the files 
cp -R "$folder"/* "$temp_dir"

#search the instances of the keyword 

grep -r "$keyword" "$temp_dir"

#delete the temp folder 

rm -rf "$temp_dir"
```